# Segmentation Fault in Assembly Language

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am learning AT&T x86 assembly language. I am trying to write an assembly program which takes an integer n, and then return the result (n/2+n/3+n/4). Here is what I have done:

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    pushl $24
    call profit
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80

profit:
    popl %ebx
    popl %eax
    mov $0, %esi
    movl $4, %ebp
    div %ebp
    addl %eax, %esi
    movl %ecx, %eax
    movl $3, %ebp
    div %ebp
    addl %eax, %esi
    movl %ecx, %eax
    movl $2, %ebp
    div %ebp
    addl %eax, %esi
    movl %esi, %eax
    cmpl %ecx, %esi
    jg end
    pushl %ebx
    ret

end:
    mov %ecx, %eax
    ret
```

The problem is I am getting segmentation fault. Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what is going on ?

Comment: AT&T branched into processors? (-:

Comment: tripleee: "AT&T syntax" refers to the assembler syntax above, originally used in SysV Unix.  It puts the operand size onto the instruction as a suffix, uses a "%" to tag register names, and puts the destination register at the end of the list.  It's the syntax supported by the GNU assembler on linux.  It's quite different from "Intel" syntax used more commonly in the PC industry.

Comment: If you're going to learn Intel assembly language, use Intel syntax. In a decent world, that abomination you're calling AT&T syntax would never have existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the code fails here:

```
_start:
    pushl $24
    call profit
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80

profit:
    popl %ebx
    popl %eax
```

So, you `push $24` (4 bytes) and then `call profit`, which pushes `eip` and jumps to `profit`. Then you pop the value of `eip` into `ebx` and the value `$24` into `eax`.

Then, in the end, if `jg end` branches to `end:`, then the stack won't hold a valid return address and `ret` will fail. You probably need `pushl %ebx` there too.

```
    cmpl %ecx, %esi
    jg end
    pushl %ebx
    ret

end:
    mov %ecx, %eax
    ; `pushl %ebx` is needed here!
    ret
```

Comment: Good level of detail in explanation.  nice.

Comment: The normal and more efficient solution is to leave the return address on the stack and access the first arg with `mov 4(%esp), %eax`.  (Or whatever offset it's at if you push something else first).  If you make a traditional stack frame with EBP, you'd be able to access the first arg as `8(%ebp)` regardless of other pushes.

Answer (score 2):

1. you use `ecx` without ever explicitly initializing it (I'm not sure if Linux will guarantee the state of `ecx` when the process starts - looks like it's `0` in practice if not by rule)
2. when the program takes the `jg end` jump near the end of the procedure, the return address is no longer on the stack, so `ret` will transfer control to some garbage address.

Answer (score 2):

You do not appear to be doing function calls correctly. You need to read and understand the x86 ABI ([32-bit](http://Fwww.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), [64-bit](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)) particularly the "calling convention" sections.

Also, this is not your immediate problem, but: Don't write `_start`, write `main` as if this were a C program.  When you start doing something more complicated, you will want the C library to be available, and that means you have to let it initialize itself.  Relatedly, *do not* make your own system calls; call the wrappers in the C library.  That insulates you from low-level changes in the kernel interface, ensures that `errno` is available, and so on.

Comment: The question is about segmentation fault in *assembly* language, not about using *inline assebly in C* nor how to use wrappers for system calls. `_start` is perfectly valid here this being a pure assembly program.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you pop the return address off of the stack and when you branch to end you don't restore it. A quick fix is to add `push %ebx` there as well.

What you should do is modify your procedure so it uses the calling convention correctly. In Linux, the caller function is expected to clean the arguments from the stack, so your procedure should leave them where they are.

Instead of doing this to get the argument and then restoring the return address later

```
popl %ebx
popl %eax
```

You should do this and leave the return address and arguments where they are

```
movl 4(%esp), %eax
```

and get rid of the code that pushes the return address back onto the stack. You then should add

```
subl $4, %esp
```

after the call to the procedure to remove the argument from the stack. It's important to follow this convention correctly if you want to be able to call your assembly procedures from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have a single pushl before you call profit and then the first thing that profit does is to do two popl instructions.  I would expect that this would pop the value you pushed onto the stack as well as the return code so that your ret would not work.

push and pop should be the same number of times.

call pushes the return address onto the stack.